# Is there a software way to make the screen more readable?

Tags: screen, brightness

I have a Lenovo Carbon X1 laptop. Often when it's sunny outside I can barely read the screen, even at the brightest setting.

Is there a software tool that has something like a "crazy contrast mode", or "inverted mode"? Something that does any kind of trick to make the screen a bit more readable?

Comment: There is a high-contrast theme. Easiest way to activate that is to install "Unity Tweak" and look under "Themes". Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Ubuntu **System Settings**. Then go to *Appearance*.

In the *Look* tab, there is *Theme* setting. The default is called *Ambiance*, but you can also pick *High Contrast*, which gives you a hard black and white contrast.

Furthermore, you can set a keyboard shortcut for switching to high contrast in **System Settings**->*Keyboard*->*Shortcuts*->*Universal Access*.

Comment: Upvoted, but not  really what I'm looking for. Many apps need custom (matching) themes (e.g. `geany`, `eclipse`, `meld`), and they become unusable if you switch from one theme to another, especially dark vs. light.

Comment: I see. I am afraid, I don't think I can be of help in that case.